# Windows application deployment

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, deployment

How to deploy windows form application? I am using visual studio. I tried copying the `.exe` file but it does not work.

I'd read an article that, to deploy windows application from visual studio `right click solution explore` -> `click publish` and so on. Then it creates an installer. Was it true? If yes, does my connection strings will be affected?

Answer (score 1):

yes it will creates the setup of click once you can read out more here about click once
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx

for the connection string will not affected if it is made to run only in one machine.

if you want to ask connection string to user then i think better to use installshiled for visual studio. it is for free and you can creates the setup to deploy the windows application.
see below 
[image]